# Passing custom arguments to controllers in mvc3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any way to pass arguments to controllers while defining the route table ?

so the same controller can be used for two or more "sections" e.g.

```
http://site.com/BizContacts   // internal catid = 1 defined in the route        
http://site.com/HomeContacts   // internal catid = 3
http://site.com/OtherContacts   // internal catid = 4
```

and the controller gets the custom argument defined in the route table to filter and display the data by that additional parameter

so in the example above the index action will be shown and the data shown will be returned by a query such as

```
 select * from contacts where cat_id = {argument} // 1 or 3 or 4
```

i hope this is somewhat clear

any help is appreciated ?

Comment: If the category names will be unique, why not use them as your filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom route:

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _slugs;

    public MyRoute(IDictionary<string, string> slugs)
        : base(
        "{slug}", 
        new RouteValueDictionary(new 
        { 
            controller = "categories", action = "index" 
        }), 
        new RouteValueDictionary(GetDefaults(slugs)), 
        new MvcRouteHandler()
    )
    {
        _slugs = new Dictionary<string, string>(
            slugs, 
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
        );
    }

    private static object GetDefaults(IDictionary<string, string> slugs)
    {
        return new { slug = string.Join("|", slugs.Keys) };
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var slug = rd.Values["slug"] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))
        {
            string id;
            if (_slugs.TryGetValue(slug, out id))
            {
                rd.Values["id"] = id;
            }
        }
        return rd;
    }
}
```

which could be registered in `Application_Start` in `global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(
        "MyRoute", 
        new MyRoute(
            new Dictionary<string, string> 
            { 
                { "BizContacts", "1" },
                { "HomeContacts", "3" },
                { "OtherContacts", "4" },
            }
        )
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and finally you could have your CategoriesController:

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now:

- `http://localhost:7060/bizcontacts` will hit the `Index` action of `Categories` controller and pass id=1
- `http://localhost:7060/homecontacts` will hit the `Index` action of `Categories` controller and pass id=3
- `http://localhost:7060/othercontacts` will hit the `Index` action of `Categories` controller and pass id=4

Comment: looks good, will this support other actions in the category controller ? e.g. site.com/BizContacts/Edit/4 etc. ?

Comment: @Kumar, no, it won't. But you could update it to support by changing the base constructor call. Also you might need to change the `{id}` route parameter to `{categoryid}` in order to more clearly distinguish between it and the one at the end of the url.